# I want to Hide those Select Box which has null value selected

Tags: jquery

Want to hide only those select box which has null value selected. Here is my Html structure.

```
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select" class="date-month">
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
<select name="select" class="date-month">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and I am using following code but its not working.

```
 $('.date-month').each(function() {
                var a=$('.date-month').find('option:selected').val();
                if(a==''){
                $(this).hide();
                }
});
```

Comment: try `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`

Comment: There is not answered.

Comment: I've made an answer, but still a bit unsure about what exactly it is you want.

Comment: You have asked practically the same question twice. You should use the edit feature to change your original question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This code hides all `select` that "DONT" have an option selected.

Is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.date-month').each(function() {
    var c = 0;
    $.each($(this).find("option:selected"), function(i, x) {
      if ($(x).val() !== '') {
        c++;
      }
    })
    if (c == 0) {
      $(this).hide()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
  <select name="select1" class="date-month">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <select name="select2" class="date-month">
<option value="">select</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">Mar</option>
<option value="4">Apr</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">Jun</option>
<option value="7">Jul</option>
<option value="8">Aug</option>
</select>
</div>
```